# Square every digit in JavaScript - string * string become a number?

Tags: javascript, string

I am very new to JavaScript and still learning the fundamentals. I was completing a JavaScript challenge were i needed to square every number eg. 881 become 64641. My code is below which i am happy with but I have managed to get myself confused by overthinking.

When i do `numArray[i] * numArray[i]` as they are both strings does JavaScript automatically convert to a number in order for the numbers to square themselves. Did it turn it into a number - square the number - then turn back into a string again. Which is why i have to do `Number(squareArray.join(''));`

The reason i ask is I know that if you do string * number it turns to a number, i would if something similar happens. If I am wrong please can someone explain so I can understand.

```
let numArray = num.toString();   //turn number to a string
let squareArray = [];   // create an array to save the new values of the string
for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {   // iterate through the string
 squareArray[i] = numArray[i] * numArray[i];   // save the square of the number to the array 
  }
return Number(squareArray.join(''));   // turn the array into a string and then into a number}
```

Comment: It looks coerced at `numArray[i] * numArray[i]` there's a `*` operand

Comment: Yes, arithmetic operations automatically convert strings to numbers. The exception is `+`, because this is also string concatenation.

Comment: @Barmar - so once it converts the string to number - does it turn back into a string in the `squareArray`(e.g. '9' * '9' would be '81'). Which then you need to convert that string into a number using `Number(squareArray.join(' '));` (e.g. becoming a number of 81).

Comment: `.join()` converts the numbers to strings.

Comment: The general rule is that if an operation needs a parameter to be a specific type, it will usually convert it automatically. Since `join()` only works with strings, it converts the array elements. And `*` only works with numbers, so it converts them.

Comment: Note to add to Barmar's comment on `+`  is true (ex. `A` + `B` => `"AB"`)  prefixing a variable with `+` can coerce String to Number (ex. `+A` )

Comment: @LiBee I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: @CreativeLearner this is great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few observations **:**

- As you want to make a square of a number, why converting those into a string ? Keep it in number form.
- As you want each square number element should concat beside each other. You can achieve that only by joining via [Array.join('')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Suggestion **:** Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get square of each number.

**Working Demo :**

```js
let numArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

const squareArray = numArray.map(item => item * item);

console.log(Number(squareArray.join('')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise one-liner solution

```js
const squareEveryNum = (num) => +Array.from(`${num}`, v => v * v).join("")
```

- `Array.from()` creates a new shallow-copied Array instance from an iterable or array-like object. e.g `Array.from("123")` OR `Array.from([2,4,5})`
- Second argument of `Array.from()` takes callback function to be called on each element of array.
  `Array.from('223', v => v * v)  // [4,4,9]`
- `.join()` returns string by concatenating all elements of the array.
- `+` converts string to number.

Links [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from),
[Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)